# Liquibase with multi module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase, multi-module

I have two modules in the project (`integrationTest` and `main`) running the integration test. I expect that before the test itself, my application will start and roll migrations using liquibase, but since I run applications through the integration test module liquibase is looking for a master file regarding this module that leads to an error. Because master file lies in the module with miom application (`main`)

The structure of my project looks like this (some classes are omitted for compactness):

```
PROJECT
└───dataMigration
    │   build.gradle
    │
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   │     Application.java
        │   │
        │   └───resources
        │       │   application.yml
        │       │
        │       └───db
        │           └───changelog
        │                   db.changelog-master.xml
        │                   db.changelog-1.0.xml
        │        
        └──integrationTest
               ├───java
               │     IntegrationTest.java
               │
               └───resources
                       application-integration-tests.yml
```

If I run integration tests, then I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
```

If I run my application as usual (from the `main` module) then everything works.

How to make the application understand that the master file is in the module with the application itself, and not in the integration test module?

Comment: How and where do you specify the location of db.changelog-master.xml ?

Comment: I specified the location db.changelog-master.xml file in application-integration-tests.yml

Comment: `change-log: classpath:../../main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `resources` directory should be a part of the `classpath`, you may specify the master changelog file location as:

`change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

Comment: Yes, in that case. Liquibase will look for the db.changelog-master.xml file in the integrationTest module

Comment: But I need to tell liquibase that db.changelog-master.xml is in the `main` module

Comment: Then you should make sure, that `src/main/resources` direcrtory is included in classpath. Try altering `build.gradle` to include it.

Comment: you can use the maven-remote-resources plugin. But you may get an: Found X files that match classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml error afterwards.